# Pandas pivot_table and categorical variables as values

Tags: python, pandas

I am puzzled by how `pivot_table` works with categorical variables used as values.

I did search the web for pandas pivot_table categorical variables and I do find some information, but nothing that really explains to my why I see what I see.

Test dataframe:

```
test_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'val': ['pass','pass','fail','pass'], "col_a": ['a','b','a','b'], "col_b": ['x','x','y','y']})
test_df
    val col_a   col_b
0   pass    a   x
1   pass    b   x
2   fail    a   y
3   pass    b   y
```

Then I proceed to reshape it. I come from R/data.tables where this would be a cast.

```
test_df.pivot_table(index = "col_a", columns = "col_b", values = 'val')
```

and I get this:

```
/tmp/ipykernel_153608/3910840210.py:1: FutureWarning:

Dropping invalid columns in DataFrameGroupBy.mean is deprecated. In a future version, a TypeError will be raised. Before calling .mean, select only columns which should be valid for the function.

col_b
col_a
a
b
```

Empty result, but with indices.
After doing a million tests (on my real object, such as testing if there were duplicated values, NAs, etc), this seems to work:

```
test_df.pivot_table(index = "col_a", columns = "col_b", values = 'val', aggfunc=lambda x: x)
col_b   x   y
col_a       
a   pass    fail
b   pass    pass
```

which is what I want.
Besides the "dude, if it works, take it and be happy", does anyone know why I have to put the aggregation function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html) exists in order to aggregate data. If you just want to `pivot` the data and not aggregate it, then use `pivot`:

```
test_df.pivot(index='col_a', columns='col_b')

        val      
col_b     x     y
col_a            
a      pass  fail
b      pass  pass
```

In your actual data, IF there are duplicates, then *you would need to aggregate data* and use `pivot_table` with `first()` or something.

Comment: so you mean that `pivot_table` is not supposed to work without `aggfunc`?

Comment: @mic technically, but per the docs `aggfunc='mean'` is the default, so you do not have to pass it if you are calculating the mean.

Comment: aaaaaaaahhhhhh that's why it "fails". I'd like that to fail with some warning like "dude I cannot do a mean of a categorical variable" rather than giving me a nice empty table